# Simplify combinatorics N choose K

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

[image]

How did the author simplify $x-b$ to $b-1$ ?

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$

Comment: ok. I got it. thanks!